# Hamlit for begginers

Tags: html, ruby, haml, hamlit

Hamlit is another implementation of Haml. The author says it is 2.39x faster than Haml.

How do you use Hamlit? Do you use it like Haml?  Does it have the same syntax? Do I need to replace the `.haml` extension with `.hamlit`?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the documentation of [HAMLIT](https://github.com/k0kubun/hamlit), you only have to replace the `gem "haml"` in your gemfile with `gem "hamlit"`.

> Add this line to your application's Gemfile or just replace gem "haml"
>   with gem "hamlit". It enables rendering by Hamlit for *.haml
>   automatically.

So I guess that there is not a specific implementation, you can use standard HAML syntax

Comment: can you please advise, on how should i change the gemfile? I have installed both gem 'haml' and gem 'hamlit' on my computer. By the way, I am using Windows.

Comment: if you are running ruby with RubyOnRails, you must have a gemfile in the root of your project. This is in this file that you have to replace the gem

Comment: https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/Gemfile - this is the gemfile for HAML. I don't see any 'gem "haml" '. Maybe i am not in the right place?